# How to transform equation into linear

Tags: regression, data-transformation, linear

I would like to write the following models in a form (using suitable transformations on
either x or Y ) where the new dependent variable, call it $Y˜$ , is linear in the new predictor, call it $x˜$.

How can I define the new Betas ($β˜_0$, $β˜_1$) are in terms of the old Betas ($β_0$, $β_1$)? Or is it impossible?

In my case the additive noise in the original model should be ignored.

1)
Y ≈ $β_0$ + ${β_1}^x$

For this one I thought $˜x=logx$, however I'm not sure if this is correct and I don#t know how to write the new beta in terms of the old betas.

Y ≈ $β_0$ * ${β_1}^x$

Y ≈ $β_0$ * ${x^β}_1$

$e^Y$ ≈ $β_0$  * ${x^β}_1$

Comment: This is clearly self-study, so please add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1):

The following transformation centers $Y$ on $\beta_0$, while $x$ retains its original meaning.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\ Y &=&\beta_0 + \beta_1^{x} \\
\ Y-\beta_0 &=& \beta_1 ^{x}\\
\ log(Y-\beta_0) &=& log(\beta_1) \cdot x\\
\ \tilde{Y} &=& \tilde{\beta_1} x 
\end{eqnarray*}
Where $\tilde{\beta_1} = log(\beta_1)$. The original intercept cannot be identified anymore.

The following question might be useful as well: 
[Transform this non linear model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1x_1^{\beta_2}+\epsilon$ to a linear model $y^*=X\beta^*+\epsilon^*$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235705/transform-this-non-linear-model-y-beta-0-beta-1x-1-beta-2-epsilon-to-a-l?rq=1)